# C++ Call a function in a derived class from base class without casting and no virtual methods

Tags: c++, inheritance

I was recently asked this question in an interview:

```
#include <iostream>
class Base
{
public:
    void foo() { std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void bar() { std::cout << "bar" << std::endl; }
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    Base *p = new Derived;
    // additional code here
    return 0;
}
```

The conditions on the question were that the Base and Derived classes cannot be changed (for example changing the name of the methods, adding additional methods, or changing a method to virtual.
A further restriction was that no type of cast could be used.
The pointer p had to be used.
Other than that, you could write any additional code, including as many classes as necessary to insure that the "bar()" method was called using the object pointed to by p.

Given that no casts were allowed, the only aswer I could come up with was an old-school one:

```
Derived *d;
memcpy(&d, &p, sizeof p);
d->bar();
```

Which is even worse than a cast.
The interviewer berated me and told me I didn't have even the most basic knowledge of object hierarchy since I could not see the very obvious, trivial solution to the question.

I apologize if this question is a duplicate; I've seen other questions about accessing a method in a derived class from a base class, but in all cases I saw, the answer involved either a cast or modification to either of the classes.

He may be correct; I've been programming in C++ for over 15 years and I cannot see the solution.  It could be I've never encountered it since I would use a cast in this situation: in this case, it would have to be a static_cast since there are no virtual methods (not even the destructor) which would allow the dynamic_vast to compile (it fails with a message: "'Base' is not a polymorphic type"

Comment: Please fix the code so that it compiles and makes sense (e.g. what is the relationship between Base and Derived?)

Comment: non static method I assume?

Comment: maybe the point was to make Derived derive from Base?

Comment: @Blob, You can't change the class, but I suspect they were actually set up that way. Even then, I still can't think of a simple solution.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to fix the code?

Comment: Well maybe the answer he expected was: This will not compile :) Because it doesn't.

Comment: Have you actually asked said interviewer what his solution is?

Comment: there is a '}' missing at the end of 'bar()'. I tried to edit, but it wasnt possible because its less than 6 characters :(

Comment: Be glad you didn't get to work there.

Comment: Shouldn't `Derived`, you know, derive from `Base`?

Comment: there is something fishy about the question. Are you sure that you arent missing some detail? Given the two classes cannot be changed, "...insure that the "bar()" method was called using the object pointed to by p" does not make much sense to me, because already 'Base *p = new Derived;' fails to compile, thus p isnt pointing to anything

Comment: Sorry -- I fixed the inheritance

Comment: The only way to call `bar` is to provide facilities in `Base`, cast it to `Derived` or bypass the typechecker. Since your question excludes the first two, you are certainly in "nasty hack that can break things" territory by implementing whatever you decide to do.

Comment: I agree, further, he refused to tell me the answer, stating that it was obvious to anyone with even the most basic understating of how inheritance worked.

Comment: @Xaq: Silly, no reason to not provide a learning opportunity for the interviewee.

Comment: @Guvante, I think that would have removed power from him in his eye, afterall knowledge is power

Answer (score 6):

Simple and <del>easy</del> dumb:

```
#define Base Derived
```

just before `main`. (you can then call `bar` on it)

Comment: All I have to say is wow. I would hate that interview question.

Comment: Still wouldn't compile ;-)

Comment: @chris answer it, then get up and say "if this is the way you do things, I probably wouldn't fit here" :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, If I wasn't a desperate co-op student maybe :) I could probably stand four months.

Comment: I don't think that is the answer that demonstrates "simple, obvious" knowledge of C++ inheritance.

Comment: @Xaq defines? Plus, you added an inheritance level in the question, that's a pretty major "detail"

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: The prose had it from the beginning. It's just that the code was buggy (this is the 4th defect corrected, 2 by me, 1 by you, 1 by OP).

Comment: Sorry -- my oversight in posting the original question, I forgot to indicate Derived was "public Base"

Answer (score 2):

I maybe would come up with something like:

```
void foobar(Base* b){
   Derived d;
   d.bar();    
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){
    Base *p = new Derived;
    foobar(p);
    return 0;
}
```

And if the interviewer complains that this is too foobar, I would ask him to please ask less foobar questions :P

No, really, I do consider this as a valid answer to a quite academic question. I am using the object pointed by p (to call a foobar function) and I made sure that 'bar()' is called. I dont think such an exercise deserves a more sophisticated solution. Logically, my solution cannot be distinguished from whatever solution the interviewer had in mind.

Comment: Well, I think this question really actually asks for a "worst abuse of the rules"-answer, so +1. IOCCC greets you, this time in C++.

Answer (score 1):

> The pointer p had to be used. Other than that, you could write any additional code, including as many classes as necessary to insure that the "bar()" method was called using the object pointed to by p.

As many classes as necessary, you say?

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    void foo() { std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void bar() { std::cout << "bar" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    class Base
    {
    public:
        void bar() { std::cout << "bar" << std::endl; }
    };
    class Derived : public Base
    {
    };
    Base *p = new Derived;
    p->bar();
}
```

Comment: Well, that's cheating. Because you don't actually use the pointer anymore, you made it into something else. Although *this* interviewer may have expected this answer. I guess we'll never know.

Comment: @ChristianHackl The interviewer definitely didn't expect the `#define Base Derived` answer.

Comment: Yeah, that answer suffers from the same problem, of course. Perhaps the interviewer did expect it, perhaps he didn't. It's just a very stupid question, and I feel sorry for the OP who wasted his time trying to get into a company like that.

Comment: "The conditions on the question were that the Base and Derived classes cannot be changed" - `class Derived : public Base` definitely changes the classes.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Oops, removed. The classes inside main() are my own, so they're fine.

Comment: @Blob: OP fixed the code to be in line with the prose, not the other way around. So you can undo your fix to do it like the code.

Comment: That's just hiding the classes, not using the classes supplied.  Based on other answers I gave him, he'd say the classes have to have different names.  During this interview, whenever I gave an answer he was not expecting that answered the question, he changed the question to try to steer me to the one answer he wanted that he likely read in a textbook

Comment: @Xaq: Or he wanted to test your reaction to the question to see how you'd cope with a superior's weak technology competence. Which is still very poor interview style. As I said, be glad you don't have to work there and find a better company, one which does not play games with candidates.

Comment: @Christian, I agree -- for many of the questions he asked, he told me I was wrong when I knew I was right and kept hammering at me, telling me I was wrong to see if I would change my assertion.  But for the question, I really think he found something he thought was "really cool" in either a book or some website and wanted to see if anyone else could come up with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `union` for type-punning:

```
union {
    Base* bp;
    Derived* dp;
} my_union = {p};
my_union.dp->bar();
```

Comment: I could, but that basically performs the same operation as the memcpy -- not what he was looking for

Comment: So what was he looking for?

Comment: @trenki He refused to give me the answer, only stating that I could created as many new classes as necessary to solve the problem.
I also implement a MyDerived class that was public Derived and took a Base * as a parameter to the constructor and that used placement new to use it, but he didn't like that either.
He kept saying that it was simple and I needed to implement some additional classes (not in main)

Answer (score -1):

Answer could be: This will not compile.

Comment: I forgot to indicate Derived is public Base.  I've fixed it now.